# how to know the type of symmetric encryption used by ssh?

Tags: ssh, security, encryption

I want to know the type of symmetric encryption (after authentication) used by ssh in a connection client-server. I'm not sure who determines the encryption. Client or Server?.

I have looked in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (on client) and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (on server)  and nothing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Both `ssh_config` (client configuration) and `sshd_config` (server configuration) have a `Ciphers` option that determine the supported ciphers. If the option doesn't appear in the configuration file, a built-in default applies. It is mentioned in the manual page for your version (unless your distribution tweaked the list at compile time without updated the man page). The actual cipher for a given connection is determined according to [RFC 4253](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4253.txt):

> The chosen encryption algorithm to each direction MUST be the first algorithm on the client's name-list that is also on the server's name-list.

You can see what both parties had to offer and which cipher was chosen for a given connection by running `ssh -vv`.

Answer (score 10):

The client and server both have to agree about which cipher to use, so nobody really "determines" the encryption -- both config files have a `Ciphers` option.

You can see which cipher is used using `ssh -vv`:

```
$ ssh -vv guthrie
[...]
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
[...]
```